# How to add values from multiple nodes from XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Say if I have an xml document as:

```
<nutrition>
<food>
<value>2</value>
</food>
<food>
<value>4</value>
</food>
</nutrition>
```

Then how do I add the two values, using XSLT, like 2+4?

I have tried sum function in XSLT, but it doesn not work in inner tags.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select='sum(nutrition/food/value)'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: + Correct answer. But, there is no need for starting `//` operator.

Answer (score 0):

> Then how do I add the two values,
>   using XSLT, like 2+4?

**Use**:

```
/*/food[1]/value + /*/food[2]/value
```

> I have tried sum function in XSLT, but
>   it doesn not work in inner tags

You don't need the `sum()` function to add just two numbers together. Whenever the number of `food` elements in  an XML document having the format of the provided XML document is great, **use**:

```
sum(/*/food/value)
```

**This is a very basic XPath question** -- you must get introduced to at least the fundamentals of XPath and XSLT via a short tutorial or a more serious book. See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589)** for a list of such tutorials/books.